# Save XML string from urllib python

Tags: python, xml, google-maps, urllib

Im trying to save a xml that I fetched from a Url (from google maps API) and I get argument must be str, not bytes, here is the code

```
con=urllib.request.urlopen("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Limon,CR&key=AIzaSyBeR0hUS1myPd7oa2LjJ2F6Vl37b-rUfVo")
def saveXml:
    data=con.read()
    f=open("xml2.xml","a")
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question and/or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either open the file in binary mode:

```
def saveXml():
    data = con.read()
    with open('xml2.xml', 'ab') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Or convert the binary data to text (if you know the encoding is, say, UTF-8.)

```
def saveXml():
    data = con.read().decode('UTF-8')
    with open('xml2.xml', 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)
```